# How to return non undefined values in Hapijs api from Amazon DynamoDB Javascript SDK query?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, async-await, amazon-dynamodb, hapi.js

This one has been driving me crazy for 2 days now .
I merely want to return a value : from Amazon DynamoDB Javascript SDK to a specific route in hapijs.

My configuration is :

- nodejs : v9.5.0
- and from package.json :
  - "hapi": "^16.6.2",

  ```
  - "aws-sdk": "^2.183.0",

  - "babel-core": "^6.26.0",

  - "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  ```

My expurged route.js file is the following:

```
    import _myConfig from './config';
    import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
    import SESSIONS from './CRUD-sessions.js';
    
    AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "XXXXXXXX",
    secretAccessKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    region: "us-east-1",
    httpOptions: {timeout: 500}
    });
    
    const routes = [
    { 
    path: '/retrieveLastSession',
    method: 'GET',
    handler: async ( request, reply ) => {
        var myLastSession = await SESSIONS.retrieveLastSession(console, "myEmail@gmail.com");
        console.debug("myLastSession: " + myLastSession);
        return reply(myLastSession).code(200);
        }   
    }

];

export default routes;
```

And my CRUD-sessions.js file :

```
'use strict';
import _myConfig from './config';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const SESSIONS =
{
  retrieveLastSession : async function (console, escapedInputEmail) {
  var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
  var params = {
            TableName: "sessions",
            "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":escapedEmail" : {"S" : escapedInputEmail} },
            "KeyConditionExpression": "email = :escapedEmail",
            "Limit": 1,
            ScanIndexForward: false
          };
  var _reply = undefined;
  await ddb.query(params, function(err, data) { 
          if (err) {
            console.error(err + ' Unable to read last session item ' + err.stack);
           } 
          else if (data === undefined || data.Items === undefined || 
            data.Items.length<1) {
            console.log('last session item empty or partly empty');
         }
         else {
             console.debug("data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
             _reply = {
            'token' : data.Items[0].token.S,
            'email': escapedInputEmail,
            'timestamp' : data.Items[0].timestamp.N
             };
          
          console.debug("last session: " + JSON.stringify(_reply));
        }
  });
  console.debug("_reply: " + JSON.stringify(_reply)); // prints undefined !!!
  return _reply;
  }
  };
  
export default SESSIONS;
```

In the route /retrieveLastSession , no matter with or without async/await combination, I never get anything else than undefined for var myLastSession!

Any idea? Help welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Found it : Rather than returning value , I made a callback function and passed it in as parameter to retrieveLastSession function.